# Google App Engine Blob Store... Syntax for changing file size?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, blobstore

I am running an python web app on google app engine.

I use the blobstore to store images that the user can upload.

```
from google.appengine.ext import blobstore
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import blobstore_handlers
```

(this is just to clarify, not the datastore, but the blobstore)

Anyways, I'm worried about possibly there being a stupid or malicious user who logs on and uploads a file of ridiculous size and fills up all of my quotas.

Is there any way to set a limit to the file size a user can upload?

Maybe 1mb? or even 5mb?

Thank you

Comment: See if [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6244969/google-app-engine-limit-file-size-upload) helps. (Possible duplicate).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can limit the size of any blob file for a given upload_url using max_bytes_per_blob
see:
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/functions#create_upload_url